# Servlet Filter Deployment Issue

Tags: tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters

I'm trying to implement Servlet Filter feature. Basically it would be, Filter->Servlet->Filter. But, the deployment is not happening. I'm completely unaware what's going on, as i'm very new to it.

Here is what i've done till now-

MyFilter.java

```
package p;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;  
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;

public class MyFilter implements Filter {
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig cfg) throws ServletException{    
}
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        out.println("Filter is invoked before.");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        out.println("Filter is invoked after.");            
    }
}
@Override
public void destroy()
{        
}    
}
```

**HelloServlet.java**

```
package p;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse     
response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>\n"+
                   "<head></head>\n"+
                   "<body>\n"+
                   "<p><h1>Servlet<h1><p>\n"+
                   "</body></html>");            
    }
    }        
    }
```

index.html

```
   <html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
   <a href="HelloServlet">Click here</a>
   </body>
   </html>
```

& at last the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"     
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>p.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/HelloServlet</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <filter>
       <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>MyFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/HelloServlet</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   <session-config>
       <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
   </session-config>
</web-app>
```

& finally some error messages

```
Starting Tomcat process...
Waiting for Tomcat...
Tomcat server started.
Incrementally deploying http://localhost:8084/WebApp5
Completed incremental distribution of http://localhost:8084/WebApp5
Incrementally redeploying http://localhost:8084/WebApp5
Deploy is in progress...
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC 
%3A%2FUsers%2FSANDEE%7E1%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%
2Fcontext264440372445081080    
3.xml&path=/WebApp5
FAIL - Deployed application at context path /WebApp5 but context  
failed to start
C:\Users\SANDEEP ROY\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApp5\nbproject\build- 
impl.xml:1045: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 9 seconds)
```

I was playing around with other projects, it seems this particular project is not being deployed, other projects are just working fine.

Also, when i build this one(which fails),theb i tried to access the localhost, from Firefox, that doesn't even load. So it seems this project is doing some harm to tomcat as well. Completely feeling blackout.

Comment: can you post the tomcat logs, they should be in the `/logs` folder of the tomcat installation

Comment: @Svetlin that folder is empty.

Comment: Maybe netbeans maintains an external location for the logs. So either find that location (look for catalina.out) or just manually deploy the app to the server and then the logs will be there.

Comment: The `filter-class`, `MyFilter` should be the fully qualified name, `p.MyFilter`. You should also learn to find the server logs, as mentioned above.

Comment: @Nikos, great it works now, thanks a lot.